# MSVC istream implementation locking buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, iostream, istream

I'm working with some existing code which is deserializing objects stored in text files (I potentially need to read tens of millions of these). The contents of the file are first read into a `wstring` and then it makes a `wistringstream` from that.  Running the Very Sleepy profiler on the program shows that it is spending about 20% of its time in the following call stacks:

```
Mtxlock or RtlEnterCritialSection
std::_Mutex::_Lock
std::flush
std::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::get
<rest of my program>
```

and similar ones with `std::_Mutex::_Unlock`. I'm using Visual C++ 2008.

Looking in `istream`, I see that it constructs a `sentry` object which calls `_Lock` and `_Unlock` methods on the underlying `basic_streambuf`.  This in turn just call `_Lock` and `_Unlock` on a `_Mutex` associated with that buffer.  These are then defined as follows:

```
#if _MULTI_THREAD
    // actually defines non-empty _Lock() and _Unlock() methods
#else /* _MULTI_THREAD */
    void _Lock()
    {   // do nothing
    }

void _Unlock()
    {   // do nothing
    }
#endif /* _MULTI_THREAD */
```

It looks like _MULTI_THREAD is set in `yvals.h` as

```
#define _MULTI_THREAD   1   /* nontrivial locks if multithreaded */
```

Now, I know there will never be another thread trying to access this buffer, but it looks to me like there's no way around this locking while using the standard iostreams, which seems both odd and frustrating.  Am I missing something?  Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out accessing the underlying buffer directly by replacing things like

```
c = _text_in->get();
```

with things like this

```
c = _text_in->rdbuf()->sbumpc();
```

fixed the problem and provided a big boost to performance.

Comment: If you only need unformatted data then you don't have to create an istream at all. All that you need to create is the `std::filebuf` object.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value for Runtime Library in Project properties, C/C++, Code Generation.  If it's multi-threaded, change it to a non-multithreaded version.

In any version after Visual C++ 7.1 (!), you are out of luck [as it's been removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), and you are stuck with the multithreaded CRT.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Changing the Code Generation option for the project is unfortunately not something I can do, since this is part of a much larger library, some of which does need the multithreaded runtime.

Comment: I see you are on VS2008 anyhow.  So you are out of luck if you want to use `istream` - sorry...

Answer (score 0):

The `std::flush` seems senseless in your case. I can't see how you'd flush an `istream`, so I suspect it's a result of a `tie`. You may want to un-tie, i.e. call `tie(NULL)` on your `wistringstream`. That should also reduce the number of locks taken.